# Why Angular 2 is written in CommonJs module format, not in AMD?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

As mentioned by [ADDY OSMANI](https://twitter.com/addyosmani) in his [article](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)  -

> **AMD adopts a browser-first approach to development**, opting for
>   asynchronous behaviour and simplified backwards compatability but it
>   doesn't have any concept of File I/O. It supports objects, functions,
>   constructors, strings, JSON and many other types of modules, running
>   natively in the browser. It's incredibly flexible.
>
> **CommonJS on the other hand takes a server-first approach**, assuming
>   synchronous behaviour, no global baggage as John Hann would refer to
>   it as and it attempts to cater for the future (on the server). What we
>   mean by this is that because CJS supports unwrapped modules, it can
>   feel a little more close to the ES.next/Harmony specifications,
>   freeing you of the define() wrapper that AMD enforces. CJS modules
>   however only support objects as modules.

So, Angular being a client side javascript framework, should have been written in AMD module format. Please help me to understand what am I missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: *"close to the ES.next/Harmony specifications"* –  should be enough reason right there.

Comment: @deceze So would it be right to say that it is written in ES.next/Harmony/ES6 module format, not in CommonJs?

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 have it's own module – it uses **SystemJS**.

SystemJS is a library built upon es6-module-loader to provide a way to load

1. ES6 modules
2. CommonJS modules
3. AMD modules
4. global scripts.

So Angular 2 supports all these modules formats. Some developers prefer using modules that are not supporting (yet) the AMD convention.